# bash (>4.2) script timezone offset format as hours and minutes

Tags: bash

I am using GNU bash, version 4.3. How can I represent timezone as hours and minute?

Here is the code.

**./time.sh**

```
printf -v t '%(%s)T' -1
export TZ=UTC


counter=1
while [ "$counter" -le 10 ]
do
    ((t=t+600))
    printf '%(%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z)T\n' "$t"
    ((counter++))
done

echo All done
```

Here is the result.

```
#bash time.sh
18-01-17T07:29:50+0000
18-01-17T07:39:50+0000
18-01-17T07:49:50+0000
18-01-17T07:59:50+0000
18-01-17T08:09:50+0000
18-01-17T08:19:50+0000
18-01-17T08:29:50+0000
18-01-17T08:39:50+0000
18-01-17T08:49:50+0000
18-01-17T08:59:50+0000
All done
```

But I'd like to show the result format like '18-01-17T08:59:50+00:00'.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date` instead of `printf`:

```
date --iso-8601=seconds --date="@$t"
```

Note that this assumes GNU `date`; the `--iso-8601` argument does not exist in the POSIX specification. POSIX doesn't have `%:z` either (nor even `%z`), so if this needs to be portable you'll need a different solution.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I got errors that `date: invalid date ‘@’` and **$t** start at `70-01-01T00:10:00+0000`.

Comment: Check the value of `$t` right before this command executes. `printf -v t '%(%s)T' -1; date --iso-8601=seconds --date="@$t"` works fine for me. And you don't need the `%z` format option, because you're using ISO-8601 format, which is built into `date`. Edit: into _GNU_ `date` as it turns out.

Comment: Oh uh, it's my mistake. It's work that I put the timezone declare on the top of code. And `@` is useless in `--date="@$t"` in my case. Although I don't know the reason It occurred error. Anyway, thank you very much!